# Highchart - Custom Images for Labels by using html

Tags: highcharts, label

I have a highchart barchart and try to display some custom images as label in each of the bars. I try it by configuring plotOptions like this:

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            grouping: false,
            borderWidth: 0,
            groupPadding: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                useHtml: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    var score = '<img src="../Images/Icon_VPP_5Punkte" alt="5 Punkte" >';
                    if (this.color === "#e30613") score = '<img src="../Images/Icon_VPP_1Punkt" alt="1 Punkt">Test';
                    if (this.color === "#ed8c05") score = '<img src="../Images/Icon_VPP_3Punkte" alt="3 Punkte" >';
                    console.log(score);
                    return score;
                },
                inside: 'center',
                color: 'black',
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    textOutline: "0px contrast"
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

As you can see I set useHtml to "true" and set some custom formatter function like recommend here:
[Highchart Doc](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting)

But no image will be shown.
[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j1cap5y/20/)

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "useHtml" instead of "useHTML" in your code ;)

```
useHTML: true,
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t2yaq0vr/)

Comment: Oh sh**! Sorry. I had have searched for hours, just to oversee a typo. Thanks for your help